# Problem with clock picker direction in RTL bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use ClockPicker library in my project with RTL version of bootstrap. When click on input clock picker loads but with wrong direction.

[Wrong direction in clockpicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRjou.jpg)

how to solve it, thanks a lot.

Comment: That's what Right To Left is supposed to do, doesn' it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add direction in `popover` class in your html or picker css

```
.popover { direction: rtl; }
```